# Функция создания DataFrame на основе 3 других DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, обработка-данных

Столкнулся с такой вот задачей, подтолкните к решению, не могу понять как получить DataFrame из этого примера:

> Pandas DataFrame `purchases` stores information about purchases: `customer_name`, `good_name`, `good_amount`. DataFrame `goods` stores goods' prices. DataFrame `discounts` stores discounts (in %) for some customers.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

purchases = pd.DataFrame([['Alice', 'sweeties', 4],
                          ['Bob', 'chocolate', 5],
                          ['Alice', 'chocolate', 3],
                          ['Claudia', 'juice', 2]],
                        columns=['client', 'item', 'quantity'])

goods = pd.DataFrame([['sweeties', 15],
                      ['chocolate', 7],
                      ['juice', 8],
                      ['lemons', 3]], columns=['good', 'price'])

discounts = pd.DataFrame([['Alice', 10],
                         ['Bob', 5],
                         ['Patritia', 15]], 
                         columns=['client', 'discount'])

pd.assert_frame_equal(totals(purchases, goods, discounts),
                      pd.DataFrame({'chocolate': {'Alice': 18.899999999999999, 'Bob': 33.25, 'Claudia': 0.0},
                      'juice': {'Alice': 0.0, 'Bob': 0.0, 'Claudia': 16.0},
                      'lemons': {'Alice': 0.0, 'Bob': 0.0, 'Claudia': 0.0},
                      'sweeties': {'Alice': 54.0, 'Bob': 0.0, 'Claudia': 0.0}}), check_like=True)
```

> Write the function `totals(purchases, goods, discounts)`, that returns pandas DataFrame (rows contain all `customer_name`s from `purchases`, columns contain all goods from `goods`, values contain the total sum of money for particular customer and good).

**Output Example (based on Input Example data):**

```
good     sweeties  chocolate  juice  lemons
client                                     
Alice        54.0      18.90    0.0     0.0
Bob           0.0      33.25    0.0     0.0
Claudia       0.0       0.00   16.0     0.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

я бы делал это так:

```
def totals(purchases, goods, discounts):
    r = (purchases
         .merge(goods, left_on="item", right_on="good", how="outer")
         .merge(discounts, how="left")
         .fillna(0)
         .eval("""value = quantity * price * (1 - discount/100)""")
         .pivot_table(index="client", columns="good", values="value", 
                      aggfunc="sum", fill_value=0)
         .query("client != 0"))
    return r

res = totals(purchases, goods, discounts)
```

результат:

```
In [139]: res
Out[139]: 
good     chocolate  juice  lemons  sweeties
client                                     
Alice        18.90      0       0        54
Bob          33.25      0       0         0
Claudia       0.00     16       0         0
```

PS если интересно разобраться как работает решение - попробуйте запускать решение по частям с левой команды, добавляя по одной команде за шаг

Comment: Огромное спасибо, буду разбираться)